# Jquery .load() response but doesn't load content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps-api-3

I have `<a> tag in infoBubble` google map content (javascript api) and `LoadPages` div for load content from server (div fill with jquery.load())

```
"<a id='hrefShow' href='javascript:void(0);'onClick='markup(\"/Detail/job/" + item.JobId + " \");'>See More</a>"
```

and I wrote markup function last of initial map function

```
function markup(e) {
$(function () {

            if ($("#map-canvas").height() !== 320) {
                $("#map-canvas")
                    .animate({ height: 320 },
                        1000,
                        function() {
                        });
                $("#LoadPages")
                    .delay(1000)
                    .queue(function(nxt) {
                        $(this).load(e);
                        nxt();
                    });
            } else {
                $("#LoadPages").empty();

                $("#LoadPages")
                    .delay(1000)
                    .queue(function(nxt) {
                        $(this).load(e);
                        nxt();
                    });
            }
            return false;
});
```

When I click on the infoBubble content a tag everything is working correctly
get response 200 ok with HTML.

[image]

But in `LoadPages` div response (html content from server) doesn't load. Plus, I have empty div.

[image]

Why doesn't it load content, while it is loading content writing code in the click event of a button?

Comment: Looks like the `href` value is `javascript:void(0);`, no?

Comment: i edit post  please watch again